# How can I add to a already running process an additional 'shutdown' command?

Tags: command-line, bash, shutdown, process

On a regular basis I forget to add `&& shutdown -h now` to a long-running process. Is there any way to add a `shutdown -h now` command **after** the first command was invoked? It is not intended to interrupt the ongoing process. Maybe it is possible to watch the PID?

Comment: I hope you realise that whatever comes after `&&` will only run if the previous command was successful. If you want it to run even if the command fails use `;` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to repeatedly run ps to list all processes and grep through the output.  Background the process with ctrl-Z, then run

```
bg %1 ; wait %1 ; shutdown -h now
```

If you have other background jobs running, then you will be given a different jobspec instead of [1] when you ctrl-z.  If so, use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

I do this all the time.

1. Start the process.
2. Realize that I forgot to do my `&&` command.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process and return to the shell.
4. Run `fg && shutdown -h now` to:

   1. Foreground and resume the process you just suspended.
   2. Then, after it finishes, it'll run what you wanted to run.

Alternatively, you can poll as suggested in other answers like this:

```
while ps -p $PID ; do sleep 5 ; done ; shutdown -h now
```

Comment: That will shutdown right away.

Comment: The fg completes right away, so...

Comment: @psusi no it won't

Comment: @WalkingWiki, oh weird, you are right.  I swear I tested this back in 2012 and it completed right away.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, which will check whether the process is running every 5 seconds and take appropriate action:

```
while true; do
  if ps -ef | grep -q '[l]ong-running-process'; then
    sleep 5
  else
    sudo poweroff
  fi
done
```

Note the square brackets in the `grep` expression. This is to ensure that the `grep` process doesn't get matched if it ends up in the `ps` list. Surrounding any single character with square brackets is sufficient.

Comment: +1 since it works. Not the way I would have done it tho.

Comment: @Zoke: If there's another way, I'd be interested.

Comment: Posted an answer as well. Check it out if you like.

Comment: You can also use kill -0 (pid) to check for existence of a process without killing it.

Answer (score 2):

If You know the pid you can run this:

```
while ps -p $PID; sleep 5; done; shutdown -h now
```

To run without echo from ps do this:

```
while ps -p $PID >/dev/null; sleep 5; done; shutdown -h now
```

And finally to run it in the background without any output:

```
(while ps -p $PID >/dev/null; sleep 5; done; shutdown -h now ) &
```

Scott's solution is a good one but this removes the need to `grep` over and over if you already know the pid. And it's a lot quicker to type in. :p

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell script to run both processes:

MyShellScript.txt:

```
#!/bin/sh
MyProcessIdLikeToStart -o options && shutdown -h now
```

After saving this in the directory where you start the given process, do a:

```
chmod +x MyShellScript.txt
```

Then when you want to run the command just type `./MyShellScript.txt` and it'll do both for you.