# Shutdown after a running command terminate?

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown

I have a long-running command, and forgot to add `&& shutdown` to it. Is there any way to shut down my PC upon its completion, while it's running?

Comment: Write a command loop that will check whether your command is running. If it is not running then run the shutdown command.

Comment: [How can I add to a already running process an additional 'shutdown' command?](https://askubuntu.com/a/99764/986805)

Answer (score 1):

First find the corresponding pid with `pgrep`,
then run:

```bsh
while kill -0 pid; do sleep 5; done; shutdown
```

From man page of `kill`:

> If signal is 0, then no actual signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

So the condition of while loop remain true until that command terminate.

Answer (score 0):

This while loop will check if `command` has any running proceses every 10 seconds in the background and if it does not find any starts a shutdown count of +5 minutes which you can cancel with `shutdown -c`

```
$ while true; do \
    (($(pgrep -c command) > 0)) && \
      sleep 10 || { shutdown +5; exit 0; }; done &
```